# Registration Form output to be displayed in the form of a table in the same page using HTML, JS and jQuery(if needed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to create a registration form with the fields First Name, Last Name, Email, Password, Date of Birth(mm/dd/yyyy).

And then I want to display the data entered in the text box below the form in same page. Can someone help me with the code and a little explanation? And can you please use HTML and JAVASCRIPT.

And for text editor I am using JetBrains WebStorm tool.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/qft4bkbe/

Answer (score 0):

make a `<div>` as show data and use this in your script `document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = res;`